# Выставить картинки в 3 ряда с наложением текста на картинке

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как выставить картинки в три ряда, что бы на них был наложен текст и с адаптивным сжатием если убрать `<div style="position:relative">` и `<div style="position:absolute;bottom: 10px">Текст</div></div>` то всё нормально работает картинки сами выстраиваются в несколько рядов в зависимости от ширины, ну нужно с наложением текста на картинку

```css
.alb_pho {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<a href="#">
<img class="alb_pho" style=" border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg" ></a>
<div style="position:absolute;bottom: 10px">Текст</div></div>

<div style="position:relative">
<a href="#">
<img class="alb_pho" style=" border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image02.jpg" ></a>
<div style="position:absolute;bottom: 10px">Текст</div></div>

<div style="position:relative">
<a href="#">
<img class="alb_pho" style=" border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image03.jpg" ></a>
<div style="position:absolute;bottom: 10px">Текст</div></div>

<div style="position:relative">
<a href="#">
<img class="alb_pho" style=" border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg" ></a>
<div style="position:absolute;bottom: 10px">Текст</div></div>

<div style="position:relative">
<a href="#">
<img class="alb_pho" style=" border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image02.jpg" ></a>
<div style="position:absolute;bottom: 10px">Текст</div></div>

<div style="position:relative">
<a href="#">
<img class="alb_pho" style=" border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image03.jpg" ></a>
<div style="position:absolute;bottom: 10px">Текст</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```css
.alb_div {
  width: 30%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}
.alb_pho {
  width:100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;
}
.alb_title {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="alb_div">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="alb_pho" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg"></a>
  <div class="alb_title">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="alb_div">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="alb_pho" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image02.jpg"></a>
  <div class="alb_title">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="alb_div">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="alb_pho" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image03.jpg"></a>
  <div class="alb_title">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="alb_div">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="alb_pho" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image01.jpg"></a>
  <div class="alb_title">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="alb_div">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="alb_pho" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image02.jpg"></a>
  <div class="alb_title">Текст</div>
</div>

<div class="alb_div">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="alb_pho" src="http://dbmast.ru/files/responsive-images-demo/images/image03.jpg"></a>
  <div class="alb_title">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: всё работает, ещё вопрос, как их выровнять по центру, а то они сбились к левому боку

Comment: `text-align: center;` поможет вам

Comment: не работает если я правильно понимаю из за float: left; в <div class="alb_div">

Comment: В примере в ответе работает? Не забудьте указать ширину для абсолютно спозиционированного div.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, нужно выровнять по центру страницы не текст, а сами картинки, что бы всё было так же, но не прижаты к левой части страницы, а по центру

Comment: Добавляете `margin-left`

Comment: Работает спасибо.